# Redefinition of chapter count leads to double dots in tables, figures, header, and footer

Tags: formatting, renewcommand, count

In the following example the appearance of the chapter count has been redefined.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\Huge}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}.}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\chapter{House Lannister}

\section{Tywin's children}

\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{House Lannister} &
    Cersei \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Jaime \\ \cline{2-2}
    & Tyrion \\  
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table of one generation of House Lannister.}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

However, this leads to undesirable consequences which is illustrated in the table caption: the numerical reference has double dots.

[image]
[image]

How can this be adjusted to look like **Table 1.1.** in tables, or figures, header / footer, respectively?

Comment: Of course that is the case. Adding a dot at the end of a counter is not a "normal" design, so when the table counter is defined similar to `\thechapter.\arabic{table}` it assumes `\thechapter` does _not_ end with a dot. If you want counters to be typeset like that, then you will have to redefine all other `\the...` macros for counters that are prefixed by `\thechapter`.

Comment: So you would add
`\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thechapter\arabic{section}.}`in this example?

Comment: For example, yes. Personally I just would not use such a design.

Comment: I have to convert a given Word template to LaTeX, so there is no choice, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gather that one of the formatting requirements your document must satisfy is that chapter, section, and table numbers must be followed a `.` (period, aka full stop) character, both in the respective headers and in the table of contents and the list of tables.

If there's any chance at all that you'll need to create cross-references to `chapter`, `section`, or `table` objects using LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` mechanism, it would be a bad mistake to hardcode the `.` (period) character into the macros `\thechapter`, `\thesection`, and `\thetable`. Instead, I suggest you employ the capabilities of the `titlesec`, `caption`, and `tocloft` packages to meet your formatting requirement in a way that doesn't interfere with the `\label`-`\ref` cross-referencing mechanism.

Excerpt from the Table of Contents (yellow highlighting added):

[image]

Except from the List of Tables:
[image]

And the first main page:
[image]

Observe that the outputs of the three `\ref` instructions do *not* feature a "period" character.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec,tabularx,multirow}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\Huge}{\thechapter.}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\Large}{\thesection.}{20pt}{\Large}
   
\usepackage{caption}
  \captionsetup{labelsep=period}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
  \renewcommand{\cftchapaftersnum}{.}
  \renewcommand{\cftsecaftersnum}{.}
  \renewcommand{\cfttabaftersnum}{.}

\usepackage[colorlinks,linktocpage]{hyperref} % optional

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoftables

\chapter{House Lannister}  \label{chap:House}
\stepcounter{section}    % just for this example
\section{Tywin's children} \label{sec:Tywin}
\addtocounter{table}{4}  % just for this example

\begin{table}[ht!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
   \hline
   \multirow{3}{*}{House Lannister} &
        Cersei \\ \cline{2-2}
      & Jaime  \\ \cline{2-2}
      & Tyrion \\  
   \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Table of one generation of House Lannister.}
\label{tab:Lannister}
\end{table} 

\noindent
Cross-references to chapter \ref{chap:House}, section \ref{sec:Tywin}, and table \ref{tab:Lannister}.
\end{document}
```